# Run Lasso and Ridge logistic regression using statsmodels in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels, lasso-regression

I want to run Lasso and Ridge logistic regression using statsmodel. I am getting the below error. Please suggest how to fetch fit.regularised for Ridge and Lasso regression.

[image]

P.S: I want to publish summary of the model result in the below format for L1 and L2 regularisation. L1 i could generate through statsmodel (thanks Marat). Please suggest something for L2.

[image]

Comment: remove `.fit()` at the end of the `model=sm.Logit(...` line

Comment: Thank you Marat. I was struggling with this for sometime. Default method is l1. What should I do to get L2 regularization please?

Comment: L2 is not supported by statsmodels for discrete models, at least yet

Comment: Could you pls suggest any other module? Sci kit learn does not support  model.summary() for publishing summary similar to what we get in R.

Comment: I usually just use R for this

Comment: statsmodels GLM Binomial is the same underlying model as Logit and has elastic net, L1 + L2, penalization available.

Comment: just to add to @Josef point, you can use statsmodels to apply L1 and L2 regularization, but what do you need from the summary? Apparently that is the only reason for using it. The confidence interval and errors are estimated with a penalization term and especially when you approach a full lasso.. I am not so sure about the validity of these